# Google Maps API v2 doesn't work at Firefox and IE

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to use google maps v2 in my website however the map doesn't appear in firefox and ie but it appears at chrome. I can't find find the problem, Does anyone knows whats the problem in the code? The map can be viewed at http://www.ideiah.com/contato

Code:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyAPPKVsGOmTcBlOo_FkNi4QBn19RKBPMeI" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function MyIndexOf(arr, element)
{

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if( arr[i] == element)
        return i;
}
return -1;

}
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    //mapGDynamicMap2
    function GetMapIndex(map)
    {
    var currentMapType = map.getCurrentMapType();
    return MyIndexOf(map.getMapTypes(),currentMapType);
    }

    function SetMapIndex(map,mapTypeIndex)
    {
    map.setMapType(map.getMapTypes()[mapTypeIndex]);
    }


    function LoadMapmapGDynamicMap2(){
    var mapGDynamicMap2 = new GMap2(document.getElementById("GDynamicMap2"));
    mapGDynamicMap2.setCenter(new GLatLng(-29.789195,-55.768093), 17);
    mapGDynamicMap2.setMapType(mapGDynamicMap2.getMapTypes()[2]);
    SetMapIndex(mapGDynamicMap2,0);
    mapGDynamicMap2.addControl(new GMenuMapTypeControl());
    mapGDynamicMap2.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    mapGDynamicMap2.addControl(new GOverviewMapControl());

    var pointGDynamicMarker7141266 = new GLatLng(-29.789241,-55.768329);
    var GDynamicMarker7141266 = new GMarker(pointGDynamicMarker7141266, {icon:G_DEFAULT_ICON, draggable: false});
    GDynamicMarker7141266.bindInfoWindowHtml('Ideiah Soluções em Software');
    mapGDynamicMap2.addOverlay(GDynamicMarker7141266);

    GEvent.addListener(mapGDynamicMap2, "zoomend", function(){document.getElementById("mapGDynamicMap2ZoomLevel").value=mapGDynamicMap2.getZoom();;
    });
    GEvent.addListener(mapGDynamicMap2, "moveend", function(){document.getElementById("mapGDynamicMap2Center").value=mapGDynamicMap2.getCenter().toUrlValue();;
    });
    GEvent.addListener(mapGDynamicMap2, "maptypechanged", function(){document.getElementById("mapGDynamicMap2MapType").value=GetMapIndex(mapGDynamicMap2);;
    });
    }
    //]]>
</script>

<div>
<span id="mapGDynamicMap2ZoomLevel" value="17"></span>
<span id="mapGDynamicMap2Center" value="-29.789195,-55.768093" ></span>
<span id="mapGDynamicMap2MapType" value="0" ></span>
</div>
<div class="GMPdiv img-polaroid" style="width:90% !important; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div  id="GDynamicMap2" class="GMPmap" style="width:100%;height:200px;"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
LoadMapmapGDynamicMap2();//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: FYI : The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work until May 19, 2013. I suggest you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps JavaScript API.

Answer (score 3):

It's a CSS-issue, forced by the setting `max-width:100%` for `img` in [style.css](http://www.ideiah.com/assets/css/style.css)

append this to style.css:

```
#GDynamicMap2 img{max-width:none !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general rule for loading maps in the Google Maps API v2 is to either:

1. initialized them in an onload function (after the DOM is completely rendered) or
2. at the end of the page, just before the `</body>` tag (this method is extremely sensitive to invalid HTML, [these errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ideiah.com%2Fcontato&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) don't seem too problematic, but until you fix it, can't say for sure what the problem is)

You are attempting to initialize your maps inline (neither of the above).